# some kind off variable problem within php class

Tags: php, class, variables, pass-by-reference

I have this in my class

When the second function is called php errors with
wrong datatype and only variables can be past by reference.

I don't know what they mean by that

This code comes from php.net
If the same code is outside the class it executes fine

What am I doing wrong here, if I am working within a class?

```
$extensiesAllowed= array();

function __construct() {
        $this->extensiesAllowed= array("txt", "pdf");
        $this->fileName= $_FILES['file'];  
    }


    private function isAllowedExtensie($fileName) {

    return in_array(end(explode(".", $fileName)), $this->extensiesAllowed);
    }



public function check_upload() {

        if($this->fileName['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            if(isAllowedExtensie($this->fileName['name'])) {
            return true;

            }   
        }
    }
```

the php error shows

```
Array
(
    [bestandsNaam] => ACCOUNT INFO.txt
    [extensiesAllowed] => 
)
```

Thanks, Richard

Comment: This would probably be better if you could post the whole class, and also post the error message you're getting

Comment: no, there is nothing more to it
for debugging I kept the rest out, did you get the error message?
I just edited it

Comment: in exact words it was this --Only variables should be passed by reference and second--in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument and then they show what's in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting the end and explode in seperate statements - I think end() may read by reference.  In any case, it will help you figure out what line is causing you problems if it doesnt fix it.

Comment: `end()` does indeed pass by reference. An alternative is to use `pathinfo()` (http://php.net/pathinfo).

Comment: $a=explode(".", $filename);
    return in_array(end($a), $this->extensiesAllowed);

I cannot really understand it, but the error is gone.
It doesn't seem obvious to do that, because it works fine outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

In the second function/method you should call should be calling isAllowedExtensie as $this-> isAllowedExtensie()

```
if($this->isAllowedExtensie($this->fileName['name'])) {
```

Edit: forget my second comment..

Comment: oh,shit I missed that one, that is one down. Now I only have the first error left. The pass by reference error.

Comment: I don't really have an idea why but pulling the statements end() and explode() apart did the trick.